# How to change a foreign language system font in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, fonts

How is it possible to change the system font of a foreign langauge in Windows XP?

By "foreign language system font" I mean for example the font that's used in Notepad or Skype by default for the given foreign input language.

Basically I want to type in Armenian with another font (other than the default one).

Comment: they used "language packs". 2 different things (as you noted), changing the interface itself or just compatability with reading and writing the other language http://beqiraj.net/post/Windows-XP-Language-Interface-Packs-zum-Download-verfuegbar.aspx <--- there are still language packs here, but i wouldnt touch them without a Full System BACKUP. Also there were completly different CDs Supplied (aparentally) so if you want a Korean XP, you get a Korean install CD. Your question would be best updated with WHAT language you desire.  UnTested.

Comment: I just want to type in Armenian with desired font.